# Amp form submission header error

Tags: amp-html

Getting error while amp submit form

The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://local.oto.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin` instead of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

```
header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://local.oto.com');
```